# Nginx location directive

Tags: nginx

I have a `.conf` file existing in `/etc/nginx/conf.d` similar to the below

```
server {
    location /config/ {
        root /app/services/config;
        try_files $uri $uri/ $uri/config.json =404;
    }
}
```

`config.json` exists in `/app/services/config` however when my URI to the server is `/config/config.json` I am getting a 404 error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The path in the URL request is appended to the filesystem path in the `root` directive, and the result is the path which is used to find the file.

In the case you illustrated, this results in:

```
/app/services/config/config/config.json
____________________ __________________
root                 URL
```

So, you must either place your files there, or change the URL path, or change the path in the `root` directive.

Comment: so changing root to `/app/services` should suffice in this case then?

Comment: @PDStat It looks like it to me.